# PHP: passing table row as hidden element in a form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to pass the result of a SELECT query as a hidden input element in a form. Actually, I'm creating a form for every row in the result.

I know that is possible passing a hidden array in a form, so I assume it should also work passing a row of a table.

This is a snippet of the code that handles it:

```
$res = $conn->query($query);
while($row = $res->fetch()) {

    echo '<form action="action.php" method="post">';

    foreach ($row as $element) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="row[]" value="'.$element.'">';
    }

    echo '<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">';
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Now, the action.php script just prints the received row:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST['row']); echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The result of the query in mysql is

```
+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+------------+
| numero | id_producto | id_tienda | cantidad | f_pedido   |
+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+------------+
|      7 | IXUS115HSAZ |         3 |        2 | 2015-10-01 |
+--------+-------------+-----------+----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

But the print_r of the row in action.php doubles every field:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 7
    [2] => IXUS115HSAZ
    [3] => IXUS115HSAZ
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 2015-10-01
    [9] => 2015-10-01
)
```

My mistake must be somehow obvious, but I can't find where it is.

Comment: Key is `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Comment: Take a look at this (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) by default you are fetching both numeric and associative

Comment: Is there a way to get the assoc array indexes as names in the action script? the print_r() shows only numeric indexes even though I use fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) in the form now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously use `PDO`

And as you can see from a [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) - PDO `fetch` method takes as a first optional parameter a `fetch_style`.

And by default it is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` which

> returns an array indexed by **both column name and 0-indexed column number** as returned in your result set

So, you need to pass an argument to `fetch` either `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or `PDO::FETCH_NUM`:

```
while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    // ... 

    // use `$field_name` to use  database field name
    foreach ($row as $field_name => $element) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="row[' . $field_name . ']" value="'.$element.'">';
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: that works, but even if I use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, the print_r($_POST['row']) in the action script shows always numeric indexes. Is there a way to make it work with the assoc indexes (i.e. $_POST['row']['id_producto'] instead of $_POST['row'][1]  )?